# PHP scripts aren't run on localhost

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, web

I wrote a simple script and I executed it on localhost but it wasn't executed.

I am used to use Ubuntu operation system.

I've checked apache2 web server which to be run by following command :

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

After checking the service to be run I wrote simple script such a :

```
<head>
<title>THE PRACTICING FILE</title> 
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "HELLO";
?>
</body>
```

After running the script, I found out that the resulting page just shows the tages which I used in the script such as ***< title >*** tag at the top of page.
But the php codes weren't executed, In this case ***echo "Hello";*** wasn't executed.

What's wrong ? why such a thing have been occurred ? and finally how can i resolve the problem ?

Comment: What is the name of the file?

Comment: have you checked your php.ini?

Comment: Does the file end with .php and not .html?

Comment: the file name is index.php but only html tags were executed.

Comment: the only thing is be running apache, php is not configured with apache, so has nothing to do with "php.ini", if you view the source code by the browser will notice that appears the `<?php
echo "HELLO";
?>`, in other words, apache ok, but php not installed or configured in Apache.

Comment: that's it.as you said the problem was referred to the following packages of php5,libapache2-mod-php5. after installing the packages it was executed. thanks so much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache is a web server and by default serves static content, meaning HTML documents and any other kind of text or binary files as is. The way you get it to process php content and send its output is by using an Apache PHP module to invoke the PHP processor.

In order to do achieve that, make sure that:

- You have installed php and you have a php module configured for apache: `sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5`
- Your script has a `.php` extension, such as `myscript.php`, which is one of the default extensions to be handled by the php module on Apache.
- You restarted apache after installing the php module: `sudo service apache2 restart`
- You are hitting the proper page on your machine's browser, such as `http://localhost/myscript.php`, and not something like `file:///var/www/html/myscript.php`

If it still doesn't work, you can also check the logs on `/var/log/httpd/error_log` to see what went wrong.

For more info  on Ubuntu with Apache and PHP (+MySQL= LAMP), follow [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)

Comment: Thank you so much :) the problem is referred to the packages which you mentioned. after installing the packages apache web server was restarted automatically and after refreshing the page the string was showed.